# Convert PPT/PPTX file to PDF without dependency of MS Office in C#

Tags: c#, api, pdf, powerpoint

I am looking for a sample code/free api which will help me to convert ppt/pptx file to pdf file with C# code without dependency of MS Office. 
I have a requirement like, I cant take help of "Microsoft.Office.Interop" & my machine will not have installed MS Office.This will be C# code and will execute with windows programming.Even not possible to purchase any plugin/api.

I am using VS2010 & the code should be built with that.

Can you guys help me please? Any help will appreciate and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked Open Office? You can download the dlls and use in your C# program. Open office can open MS office docs and convert them. Have a look at this link: https://tinyway.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-c/

Comment: Thanks @TejSoft for your share :-)
Yes, I have installed OpenOffice in my system. I think the link you provided will be helpful for my development. Let me try on those code and get back to you asap.

Comment: Thanks @TejSoft, your given link was fruitful for me. I am done with help of that link :-)

Comment: I am glad that the suggestion helped you to solve the problem. Why don't you post an answer to the question and provide a few lines of code that you have written? Your answer might help others looking to solve a similar problem.

Comment: Hi @TejSoft , Sorry bro.I had a really busy schedule to make the post. Hope the below codes will help others a lot.

1. Install the same version(Installed open office) Open Office SDK in your system. 2. Use the codes from https://tinyway.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-c/  . 3. Get a overview from that. Then download the source code from http://www.mediafire.com/download/uryqro2cld4qeyf/ppttopdf.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. I am posting this because this may help others also.

1. Install the same version(Installed open office) Open Office SDK in your system.
2. See the link & get some overview from below link.
   https://tinyway.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-c/
3. Download the source code from
   http://www.mediafire.com/download/uryqro2cld4qeyf/ppttopdf.zip

You can also customize the code as per your requirement.